# How to tell if a parse user is logged in or not in launch screen

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have three storyboards in my ios app, the launch screen, the main storyboard, and the login storyboard.  I want to know how to tell if a parse user is logged in or not in the launch screen to then direct the app to either the main storyboard(if a user is logged in) and the login storyboard(if they are not).  The problem is when i try to do this I do not know what View Controller to instantiate in the launch screen since it is a launch screen and does not contain a view controller.  Can someone please help me , thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps for solution of your problem:

1.Store any variable or value in UserDefaults at the time of login to ensure that some user is logged in to the App.

2.In AppDelegate check for value you saved in UserDefaults.

3.If you get the value navigate the user to Landing screen else navigate user to login.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `AppDelegate` to check whether user is logged in and then use the specific storyboard:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
    let controller = AppController()

    let storyboard: UIStoryboard
    if controller.isLoggedIn() {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", Bundle.main)
    } else {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", Bundle.main)
    }

    window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
}
```

You however have to set `LaunchScreen.storyboard` as the `Main Storyboard` in your app‘s settings so it does not launch `Main.storyboard` automatically.